# In React, data fetch but not rendered using useState

Tags: reactjs

This is my Main Page (Dashboard ketua)

```
export default function DashboardKetua() {
    const [proposal, setProposal] = useState([]);
    const [lpj, setLpj] = useState([]);
    const getUserData = useAuthUser();
    const alert = useAlert();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Add loading state
    var counter = 0;


    const allKegiatans = async () => {
        const roles = getUserData().roles;
        const search = ''

        const kegiatans = await getKegiatan({roles,search})
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          alert.addAlert({
            type: ALERT_TYPE.ERROR,
            title: "Something went wrong",
            message: error.message,
          });
          return;
        })
        .finally();

        if (kegiatans) {
          setProposal(kegiatans.proposal);
          setLpj(kegiatans.lpj);
        }
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('dashboard rendered')
        allKegiatans();
    }, []);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        counter = counter + 1;
        console.log('counter', counter)
        console.log(proposal)
        console.log(lpj)
        setLoading(false);
    }, [proposal, lpj]);

    return <>
    <DefaultLayout>
        <Tab
            config={[
            {
                header: "Proposal",
                component: loading ? null : (
                    <div>
                        {proposal.length > 0 ? (
                            proposal.map((data, index) => (
                            <CardKegiatan key={index} data={data} />
                            ))
                        ) : (
                            <p>No proposals found</p>
                        )}
                    </div>
                )
            },
            {
                header: "LPJ",
                component: loading ? null : (
                    <div>
                        {lpj.length > 0 ? (
                            lpj.map((data, index) => (
                                <CardKegiatan key={index} data={data} />
                            ))
                        ) : (
                            <p>No LPJs found</p>
                        )}
                    </div>
                )
            },
            ]}
        />
    </DefaultLayout>
    </>    
}
```

So when the page loaded, the  is rendered and there is 2 CardKegiatan just for a slight moment.
Then the  disapeared not long, Why does it disapeared, how to make it not disapeared?.

This is my Tab Component

```
export default function Tab({config}) {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('tab rerendered')
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
    <div className="container bg-primary-blue px-2 pt-2">
      <ul className='tabs group'>
        {config.map((tab, index) => (
          <li  key={index} className={`tab ${activeTab === index ? 'active' : ''}`} onClick={() => setActiveTab(index)}>
            <a href='#'>{tab.header}</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div className="bg-secondary-blue rounded-tl p-5 min-h-52">
        {config[activeTab].component}
      </div>

    </div>
  
    </>
  )
}
```

I already checked the lpj state, and proposal state with the useEffect lpj and proposal.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        counter = counter + 1;
        console.log('counter', counter)
        console.log(proposal)
        console.log(lpj)
        setLoading(false);
    }, [proposal, lpj]);
```

it console logged twice. first is empty, then the second time has data. But why when my CardKegiatan rendered, it first has 2 data , but then the data disapeared please help. I've been stucked for long now :"D

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my fetch has not fully fetch the data and the data returned is not acknowledged as an array.
this is the fixed code for the fetch

```
export const getKegiatan = async (props) => {
const { roles, search } = props;
const instance = CreateAxiosInstance();
let lpj = [];
let proposal = [];
let kegiatan_id = [];

await Promise.all(roles.map(async (role) => {
    const res = await instance.post('api/kegiatan', {
        role: role,
        search: search,
    });
    const data = res.data.data || [];
    
    data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.status >= 7 && !kegiatan_id.includes(d.id)) {
            lpj.push(d);
        } else if (d.status < 7 && !kegiatan_id.includes(d.id)) {
            proposal.push(d);
        }
        kegiatan_id.push(d.id);
    });
}));

console.log(lpj);
console.log(proposal);

return { lpj, proposal };
```

}